# From which controller to extend? `sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller` or `sap.ca.scfld.md.controller.*`?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide

When I build SAP Fiori Mater Detail application, should my application controller extend from `sap.ca.scfld.md.controller.BaseDetailController` and `sap.ca.scfld.md.controller.ScfldMasterController` or just `sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller`? When I looked at sample such as Opportunity, the controllers are extended from `sap.ca.scfld.md.controller`. However, if I build
my application using Fiori template, the default controllers are extended from `sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller`, so I'm confused.